# How do I open Emacs in terminal when I double click on a file?

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp

I run Emacs with -nw mode, but when I double click on a file I want to edit from my desktop, it opens up the Emacs app outside the terminal. Is there a way to change this?

Using OSX 10.8.5 and emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

After opening Emacs, run `server-mode`. Instead of associating the double click with Emacs, associate it with emacs-client. The client will connect to the server and open the file will open in the running Emacs instance. (not tested on OSX)

Comment: I'm not sure how to associate it with emacs-client.

Comment: @garrettmartin: How did you associate it with Emacs?

Comment: I just right clicked on a file, clicked "get info", went to the "open with" dropdown and selected the emacs app. The problem is getting it to open in emacs -nw mode.